# Android studio won't execute the gradle build right

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, build.gradle

While programming an app in android studio the building process suddenly stoped working. I get 9 Errors:

```
":app:preDexDebug
Error:Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error:A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Error:Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error:A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Error:Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error:A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Error:Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error:A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat --dex --output C:\Users\NAME\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\internal_impl-21.0.3-56fc23d6165fcb12f6f6bed1589449dbd02c62e2.jar C:\Users\NAME\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-v4\21.0.3\libs\internal_impl-21.0.3.jar
Error Code:
    1
Output:
    Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
    Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit."
```

and sometimes while trying to start a Virtual Device i get this message:

```
"Failed to complete Gradle execution.

Cause:"
```

And after clicking OK in that window i get this:

```
"Unexpected Error
Local path doesn't exist. Local path doesn't exist. The project may need to be synced with Gradle files. Sync Project with Gradle files"
```

This still happens after reinstalling Android Studio and Creating a new Project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to reinstall Java. You need JDK version 1.7 for latest version.

You must download 64 bits version of JDK if you have a 64bit based SO and launch studio64 instead of studio executable.

Comment: Wow, thank you that did it. Weird that it worked in the first place and didn't crash at the start.